# Linq to Select Parent Objects Where Child Objects Have a Matching Child Object

Tags: c#, linq

How would I go about writing a LINQ statement that selects the parent objects that have a matching child object in it's collection? Here's example classes.

```
class Parent {
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

class Child {
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Nickname { get; set; }
}
```

In the example above, I would like to return all of the parents that contain a child with a specific nickname.

Comment: Voting the question down was pretty harsh. I searched SO *and* Google both before typing out this abstract answer. If the tools here were better, maybe I wouldn't have a duplicate question.

Comment: Upvoted.  This was the top result for my google search "linq select parent objects based on child objects".  If I had the rep, I would unmark this as a duplicate; the linked question provides a similar answer, but the way the question title is phrased is not intuitively similar.

Comment: Many people on SO are way too quick to perform actions, without thinking them through.  It's quite annoying and sometimes downright upsetting.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is straightfoward Linq-to-Objects:

```
listOfParents.Where(p => p.Children.Contains(childObjectToMatch))
```

For Linq-to-Entities, if the child object isn't tracked as an entity you might need to match on the child object identifier field:

```
int childObjectIdToMatch = childObjectToMatch.ID;
dbContext.Parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.ID == childObjectIdToMatch));
```